# objectspy issue of web button on a look up- dialogbox

Tags: automation, qtp

- when i try to object spy a particular look up window my system hangs up completely
- for eg :-Set strSubWindow =  Browser("title:="&strBrowserName).Window("text:=Lookup - BIC - - Web Fx -- Webpage Dialog").Page("title:=Lookup - BIC - Web Fx")
- Assume there is a search button on the window mentioned above
- when i try to object spy the search button the system hangs and needs to be restarted
- can anyone help me with it ?
- thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which technology the application is developed in? Eg: Java/.NET etc. You can use the appropriate add-in for the identification instead of using the Web add-in. I had a similar issue with an Oracle Apps application that got resolved once I had the Oracle add-in installed.

Comment: The app is developed using proC --->  is there some relevant add in?

Comment: Are you sure it is ProC? I may be wrong but I don't think  ProC can be used for generating Web UI (I am inferring that it is a web UI from the example you have given in the question). In any case, QTP does not support ProC to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: and i have the .net add in, still the problem persists ... and thanks for the response

Comment: Here are a few general troubleshooting tips for these cases (ignore any that you might have tried already)           
1. Uninstall-Re-install QTP
2. Clear Browser history
3. Make sure you have the correct .Net framework installed
Also, try accessing the object thru DP. This is more of an issue avoidance than resolution but if it works then you need not worry about the Object Spy issue. A screenshot of the application or a live link would be helpful too.